# Matrix with given characteristic polynomial is similar to its square

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a test on Wednesday and I've been dealing with this problem for quite a while. I would greatly appreciate any help or advice on how to solve it.

> Given a matrix $A$ in $\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ (space of $n$ by $n$ complex matrices), whose characteristic polynomial is $(x - 1)^n$. Prove that $A^2$ is similar to $A$.

I know that given the characteristic polynomial of $A$ posted above, it follows that
its Jordan form has ones all along the diagonal and zeroes above (I use the lower triangular convention for Jordan form). So $A$'s determinant is equal to one and $A$ is invertible (same thing for $A^2$).
I just can't get past this point.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: You just need to prove this for Jordan blocks of size $k$. It's easy to determine $A^2$, if $A$ is a jordan block of size $k$, and show that it is similar to $A$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll post the complete answer if I solve it

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Use the Jordan-Weyr theorem [See this paper in French](http://www.normalesup.org/~kortchem/travaux/jordan_young.pdf)

$$A\sim B\iff \mathrm{rank}(A-\lambda I)^k=\mathrm{rank}(B-\lambda I)^k,\quad \forall k\in \mathbb N_{\geq0}$$

and 
$$\text{if}\ B\ \text{is invertible matrix then}\ \mathrm{rank}(AB)=\mathrm{rank}(A)$$

Comment: It is certainly a great comment. I doubt if it qualifies as an answer for it is not self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ has all its eigenvalues equal to $1$. Then the Jordan form of $A$ has the form

$A'=diag(I_{i_1}+J_{i_1},\cdots,I_{i_k}+J_{i_k})$ where $i_1+\cdot+i_k=n$ and $J_k$ is the nilpotent Jordan block of dimension $k$.

Since $A'^2=diag(I_{i_1}+2J_{i_1}+{J_{i_1}}^2,\cdots,I_{i_k}+2J_{i_k}+{J_{i_k}}^2)$, it suffices to prove that $J_{k}$ and $2J_{k}+{J_{k}}^2=J_kU$ (where $U$ is invertible and commutes with $J_k$) are similar.

It's a consequence of that follows:

${J_k}^{k-1}\not=0, (J_kU)^{k-1}\not= 0,{J_k}^k=0,(J_kU)^k=0$.

Remark. In the same way, we can show that, for every $p\in\mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$, $A^p$ and $A$ are similar